# How to disable split view in Lightning Console App?

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, console, summer-17

Is there any way to **disable the split view** introduced by Salesforce in Summer '17 for **Lightning Console Apps**?

Lightning Console App User Interface :-

[image: Lightning Console App UI]

**(4) Split view lets you quickly easily see and open records from a list view.**